# Are parallel scanners supported?

Tags: scanner

Are parallel scanners supported?

I've got an Epson action scanner that I've used under Windows as a back up in case my sub died... well, it did. Tried to use the parallel, and it wasn't even recognised.

Answer (score 0):

I have in the past with my HP Scanjet [mine is a flatbed scanner], however I was using 12.04 at the time. I used SimpleScan [built into Ubuntu] for this. I think it just worked, but you may need to find drivers somewhere for it on the internet, likely the Epson website.
I hope this helps you make it work.